# Is there a trouble between wordpress and getUserMedia?

Tags: wordpress, getusermedia

Simple question :
I'm trying to find a way to capture video from user in my wordpress site (still in local mode).
I created a simple page with the code from here : https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/RecordRTC/simple-demos/video-recording.html

But the function "getUserMedia" seems to make some trouble with wordpress because I tested it in a simple html file and it works.

Do you know what wordpress stuff could create this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: getUserMedia won't work unless it is called from a page served via https. Because cybercreeps. Are you serving your test code with https? What does your browser's console log say? Please [edit] your question to give a few more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Acutally I'm working on a local server so it could be the issue. I will try again when my website will be online and with https.